# Counting projects and displaying against each row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data like below

```
Mile    proj  wit
------------------
Euapp.  Proj1 True
Euapp.  Proj2 True
Euapp.  Proj3 True
Euapp.  Proj4 Null
Assist. Proj1 True
Assist. Proj2 null
```

I want to have a Result column displayed like below:

```
Mile    proj  wit  ResULT
-------------------------
Euapp.  Proj1 True  3
Euapp.  Proj2 True  3
Euapp.  Proj3 True  3
Euapp.  Proj4 Null  3
Assist. Proj1 True  1
Assist. Proj2 null  1
```

Please help me.

Comment: It's useful when asking a question to demonstrate more effort than would inevitably be required of an answer. To that end, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: It's not very clear what your result column is. Your title says it counts projects? This is not what your example seems to show.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a window function:

```
select t.*, count(wit) over (partition by mile)
from t;
```